# Javascript repeat pattern match then output to textarea

Tags: javascript

I'm not sure how to do this with Javascript...  In order to help with understanding, I'll try to be as verbose in the opening here as I can, including a design goal.

I need to put a big block of plain text into TextAreaRaw.  Then I click a button, and a function performs the following:

1. Reads TextAreaRaw line by line
2. Regex matches for all text between any one of four patterns
3. Pattern matches from step 2 gets appended to TextAreaInfo

The text that I'll be copying into TextAreaRaw is several sets of 25 lines that follows a pattern.  It's a plain text report of purchase orders.  Of these text blocks, I only need:

1. From line 1: The text from the word "through" until the end of the line
2. From line 2: The text between the words "ID" and "Name" && the text between the words "Name" and "Entered"
3. From line 10: The beginning on the line through the first whitepace character

The lines are not actually numbered in the report, I've just provided them here to help with understanding.

- Line 1 tells us who provided the purchase order
- Line 2 tells us the customer information
- Line 10 tells us several dates

Our current method of extracting the data we need is to:

1. copy the report into a plain text editor
2. look for the information we want
3. cut the information we need from the report
4. paste it into a second text editor
5. From the second editor, we continue with our processing needs which surpasses the scope and goal of the script I'm trying to build here.

Because of security limitations, Javascript is the only client side scripting the security policy will allow. Basically, I'm stuck with notepad and a browser.

Comment: Then you go here http://learntocodewith.me/posts/code-for-free/#javascript or here https://www.freelancer.com/

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice if you included something you tried, but I guess I could help out getting you started:

There's a few things you need to do:

- Get the value from your textarea
- Split the value in to lines
- Extract the relevant lines
- Extract the relevant content from lines

I'm not going to code all the functionality for you, but I'd like to show you a few "tools" you could use to figure it out yourself:

```js
// Target the textarea that's in your HTML
var textarea = document.getElementById("myTextArea");

// Extract its value
var lines = textarea.value
  // Create an array that has a string for each line
  .split("\n")
  // Trim white space from each line
  .map(function(line) {
    return line.trim()
  });

// Create functions that take a string as an input, 
// and return the partial string you need
var getFromThrough = function(line) {
  var KEYWORD = "through";
  // You can use `indexOf` to find the index of a word/substring
  var index = line.indexOf(KEYWORD);

  // If the word's not there, `indexOf` will return -1
  if (index != -1) {
    var correctedIndex = index + KEYWORD.length;
    var end = line.length;
    // You can use `slice` or `substring` to return a string
    // based on one or two column indexes
    return line.substring(correctedIndex, end);
  }

  return null;
}

// Now, you can use the methods you've created on the lines you want to search
alert(getFromThrough(lines[0]));
```

```html
<textarea name="" id="myTextArea" cols="30" rows="25">
  This is line 1 through this is the text after line 1
  This is the second line 
  A third line
</textarea>
```